# Generic datatype in c

Tags: c, generics, unions

I'm working on a small image processing library in C.

I want to represent an image as an array of pixels which can have different types : `uint8_t` (for pixels whose the max value does not exceed 255), `uint16_t` (same but with max value at 65535), `uint32_t`.

I'm going with this for the moment :

```
typedef struct img8_t {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;
    size_t dsize;
    uint8_t *data;
}img8_t;

typedef struct img16_t {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;
    size_t dsize;
   uint16_t *data;
}img16_t;

typedef struct img32_t {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;
    size_t dsize;
    uint32_t *data;
}img32_t;
```

`dsize` contains the size of the datatype for the pixels

And I have the same number of functions to allocate/deallocate and process these images.

Is there a way to define a generic `unsigned int` type that can handle values on 8-bits, 16-bits etc.. without creating a struct/function for each case ?

Should I use a `union`?

Comment: You've got a *pointer* to the data. Use the generic pointer type: `void *`. And... you can always use `uint32_t` for every single one of these, it would just waste some memory :D

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Yeah I tried the void * solution, but I still need a datatype to cast the data if I want to access a pixel at a given index. As you said I can also use an uint32_t, but I would like to use appropriate datatype according to pixel max value. Thanks again!

Comment: Concerning image formats:  The range of `width, height, depth` are often specified by the format.  I recommend to use `uintN_t` for these members too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to define a generic "unsigned int" type that can handle values on 8-bits, 16-bits etc.. without creating a struct/function for each case ?

No, not that would suit your purpose.  Every complete C data type has a specific representation, and you can read or write objects' values only if you have a complete type for them.  You certainly could define a union that can hold different-size integers:

```
union uint_any {
    uint8_t  u8;
    uint16_t u16;
    uint32_t u32;
};
```

... but objects of that type all have the same size, which is sufficient to accommodate the largest member.  Thus, a raster of, say, 16-bit pixels without any padding between does not match up with an array of `union uint_any`, at least not if you want to read all the pixels via the `u16` member.

---

You *can* use a `void *` to point to your array, so as to avoid separate structures for each pixel size, and your functions can sort it out internally so that you need only one function for each purpose.  Additionally, if you have image manipulation functions complex enough to warrant it then you can probably benefit from reducing or eliminating code duplication by using macros.  Here's an example for a simpler case than probably warrants such treatment:

```
struct img {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;
    size_t dsize;
    void *data;
};

uint32_t get_pixel(struct img *image, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    // Warning: evaluates its first argument twice:
    #define GET_PIXEL(i,t,x,y) (((t*)((i)->data))[(x)*((i)->width)+(y)])
    switch (img.dsize) {
        case 8:
            return GET_PIXEL(image, uint8_t, x, y);
        case 16:
            return GET_PIXEL(image, uint16_t, x, y);
        case 32:
            return GET_PIXEL(image, uint32_t, x, y);
        default:
            // handle error ...
    }
    #undef GET_PIXEL
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `void *` for a generic pointer:

```
typedef struct img_t {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;
    size_t dsize;
    void *data;
} img_t;
```

Then use the `dsize` member to figure out how to cast it:

```
int value;
switch (my_img_t.dsize) {
case 8:
    value = ((uint8_t *)my_img_t.data)[idx];
    break;
case 16:
    value = ((uint16_t *)my_img_t.data)[idx];
    break;
case 32:
    value = ((uint32_t *)my_img_t.data)[idx];
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If done in C this is going to require at minimum different statements to handle the different sizes, as in:

```
void handle_img(void * ptr, unsigned size)
{
if(sizeof(uint8-_t)==sze)
{...}
else if(sizeof(uint16_t)==size)
{...}
else if(sizeof(uint32_t)==size)
{}
}
```

Depending on the exact manipulation it may make sense to break the individual handlers into separate functions. The point is that unlike C++ at some point you are going to have to write code for each branch individually.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to define a generic *unsigned int* type that can handle values on 8-bits, 16-bits etc.. without creating a struct/function for each case ?

To avoid casting, consider a `union` of pointers.

```
typedef struct imgN_t {
    unsigned int width, height, depth;
    size_t dsize;
    union {
      uint32_t *u32;
      uint16_t *u16;
      uint8_t *u8;
    } data;
} imgN_t;
```

A generic function:

```
// return widest
uint32_t img_get_pixel(imgN_t *i, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  switch (i->depth) {
    case 8: return i->data.u8[y*i->width + x];
    ...  // other sizes
    case 32: return i->data.u32[y*i->width + x];
  }
}
```

Or explicit higher performance ones for each.

```
uint8_t img_get_pixel8(imgN_t *i, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  assert(i->depth == 8);
  return i->data.u8[y*i->width + x];
}

uint16_t img_get_pixel16(imgN_t *i, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  assert(i->depth == 16);
  return i->data.u16[y*i->width + x];
}

uint32_t img_get_pixel32(imgN_t *i, unsigned x, unsigned y) {
  assert(i->depth == 32);
  return i->data.u32[y*i->width + x];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size and security requirements of your project, you may also make use of C macros to generate the generic code.

Bear in mind that this grows very ugly very fast, but it gives you type checks, e.g. assigning `1024` to `img8_t` gives you warning in compile-time, not only silent overflow in run-time. And you also implement everything once.

Example implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// declarations

#define UINT_T(SIZE) uint ## SIZE ## _t
#define IMG_T(SIZE) img ## SIZE ## _t

#define DECLARE_IMG(SIZE) \
typedef struct IMG_T(SIZE) \
{ \
    unsigned int width, height, depth; \
    size_t dsize; \
    UINT_T(SIZE) *data; \
} IMG_T(SIZE); \
\
UINT_T(SIZE) img ## SIZE ## _get_pixel(IMG_T(SIZE) *img, size_t index) \
{ \
    return img->data[index]; \
} \
\
void img ## SIZE ## _set_pixel(IMG_T(SIZE) *img, size_t index, UINT_T(SIZE) value) \
{ \
    img->data[index] = value; \
}

DECLARE_IMG(8)
DECLARE_IMG(16)

// usage

int main(void)
{
    uint8_t data[1];
    img8_t img8 = { .data = data };

    img8_set_pixel(&img8, 0, 1024U);

    printf("%u\n", img8_get_pixel(&img8, 0));

    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't give you exactly pleasant time during maintenance, but if you're writing very generic library code, it might be worth it.

You could also create custom initialization function that would set the `dsize` to proper value (e.g. `UINT ## SIZE ##_MAX`).

Answer (score 0):

Outline of this answer:

- Type-specific CPU instruction encoding.
- Intermediate code and its use in GPGPU.

As a "high-level assembly" language, C does not and cannot provide arithmetic generic types - every arithmetic operations in C have definite type.

This is because arithmetic operations compile to different CPU instructions in object code. Rarely any CPU operate on datum whose size is determined by some kind of "flag".

On the other hand, you seem to have a multimedia application, specifically, a image processing library. In multimedia applications, and in 3D and graphic intense applications, it's customary to use APIs such as OpenGL and Vulkan to accelerate image processing.

In these graphics APIs, there's the concept of "shaders", which are application programs running on GPUs. These programs are nowadays compiled from intermediate codes - SPIR-V and LLVM-IR are such examples.

If you can afford the complexity of compiling metacodes into intermediate codes before executing them somewhere on the computer, you can integrate a code generating library in your application. https://llvm.org is a well-known one in this area.